undefined symbol error _ZN5Baloo11QueryParserC1Ev while opening dolphin file manager
I am on kali linux and using the KDE desktop environment. A little while ago I was not able to launch dolphin file manager. I don't know the reason behind it as I updated and installed some packages in the time between.
Output of dolphin -v gives this

dolphin: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libKF5Baloo.so.5: undefined symbol: _ZN5Baloo11QueryParserC1Ev

This same undefined symbol also comes up when launching kate though a window still opens up.
Output for kate

qt.qpa.wayland: Wayland does not support QWindow::requestActivate()
could not open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kf5/kio/tags.so: Cannot load library /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kf5/kio/tags.so: (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libKF5Baloo.so.5: undefined symbol: _ZN5Baloo11QueryParserC1Ev)


This here is a programming Q&A site. We cannot help you fix general purpose third party software. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

The trick here is to see which issue is affecting the program.  This one is baloo5.  Track that, and you can solve it.  I reinstalled it, probably not the best idea, for glitch-hunting, but it fixed it easily enough... don't want to know what doing that probably broke on the side though.
edit that's: sudo apt reinstall libkf5baloo5
